Not able to use Pinia store getter inside my component
Here is my search.vue component (unrelated code removed):
    <template>
        <div class="tp-header-search pl-70">
          <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
            <div class="tp-header-search-wrapper d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="tp-header-search-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher des produits..." v-model="searchText" />
              </div>
              <div class="tp-header-search-category">
                <ui-nice-select :options="store.getCategories" name="Catégorie" :default-current="0"
                  @onChange="changeHandler" />
              </div>
              <div class="tp-header-search-btn">
                <button type="submit">
                  <SvgSearch />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </template>
      
      <script setup lang="ts">
      import { categoriesStore } from '@/pinia/categories/categoriesStore';
      
      const store = categoriesStore();
      
      onMounted(async () => {
        await store.fetchCategories();
      });   
      </script>

Here is my categoriesStore.ts:
    export const categoriesStore = defineStore('categories' , {
    
        state: () => ({
            categories: [],
        }),
    
        getters: {
            getCategories(state) {
                return state.categories.map(category => ({
                    value: category.slug,
                    text: category.name,
                }));
            },
        },
    
        actions: {
            async fetchCategories() {
                const base_url = useRuntimeConfig().public.baseURL;
    
                await $fetch(base_url + 'categories').then(value => {
                    this.categories = value;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }).finally(() => {
                    //
                });
            },
        },
    });

Issue: I keep getting errors on my console on this line:
<ui-nice-select :options="store.getCategories" name="Catégorie" :default-current="0" @onChange="changeHandler" />

store.getCategories is not bound correctly, even though I tried using a regular array on getCategories and it worked, here is what I tried:
    getters: {
            getCategories(state) {
                return [
                    { value: 'select-category', text: 'Catégorie' },
                    { value: 'electronics', text: 'Electronics' },
                    { value: 'fashion', text: 'Fashion' },
                    { value: 'beauty', text: 'Beauty' },
                    { value: 'jewelry', text: 'Jewelry' },
                  ];
                
                return state.categories.map(category => ({
                    value: category.slug,
                    text: category.name,
                }));
            },
        },

This worked properly, so I thought perhaps what I'm getting from the API was not correct, so I did this:
    getters: {
            getCategories(state) {
                const c = state.categories.map(category => ({
                    value: category.slug,
                    text: category.name,
                }));
    
                console.log(c);
    
                return c;
            },
        },


Where did I go wrong? Is it the way I'm formatting the data or is the way I use the getter on my component or is it something else?
